# MYSQL - This Procedure doesn't execute

Tags: mysql, sql

My Attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LoanDetails (anLoanID INT)
BEGIN
SELECT BookLoan.borrowerName, BookLoan.bookTitle
FROM BookLoan
WHERE (anLoanID = BookLoan.loanID)
END;
/

EXEC LoanDetails(8);
```

I am trying to execute this procedure in SQL *Plus but I get an error when trying to run it.

Comment: `sql*plus` is Oracle, isn't it? Are you sure you are using mysql? What Error are you getting?

Comment: use CALL, not EXEC to run an SP in mysql

Comment: seems an `INTO` clauses is missing for the select statement. Of course their respective variables too.